# Access dynamic control ids in code behind

Tags: asp.net

I am dynamically adding `<li>` elements using `HtmlGeneriControl`. And now need to access the control ids in a loop. How can I get the IDs?

Comment: The only way (from what I understand) is to make the ids by your self with some pattern, and then knowing that pattern, get the control back from the known ids

Comment: Do you intend to access them before postback (after generating them but before rendering them) or after postback?  On the server, or on the client?

Comment: Yes, I ammaking the ids by appending a number at the end to make them different. And appending all the new <li> to an existing <ui>.So when I am trying to reload the page, the new IDS are not shown. Therefore, i need to get the Ids and make them visible in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to access the `<li>` elements on the server?  You can't, as li tags don't post back.  Otherwise, in the same runtime instance, or if you are talking client, you have to ensure the ID's are unique I think.  You may get the benefits of the naming container generation for the ID (such as ct100_ContentPlaceholder_liID), but I'm not 100% sure about tha.t  That might be throwing your lookup of ID off?

I'm trying to address multiple scenarios because it really does depend on how you assign the li tags and where you are trying to retrieve them from.  We need to see code for this.

Comment: Yes, the ids are unique but dont know how to access them.

Comment: ... from the client or server?  And please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

When generating `<li>` using HtmlGeneriControl, also set the ID property.

```
var x1 = new HtmlGenericControl("li") { ID: "li1" }
var x2 = new HtmlGenericControl("li") { ID: "li2" }
```